# Paypal plus integration in Germany: only Paypal payment method appear?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have a question related to the integration Paypal Plus to the shopping cart website in Germany.

I have done the integration follows these steps from here : https://developer.paypal.com/docs/paypal-plus/germany/integrate/.

For the testing sandbox account and sandbox api everything works fine. There are some payment methods show up.

However, when I changed to use the live account and live api. Only one paypal payment method showed up. I would like to expect more than one payment method in paypal plus like: paypal, credit cart, debit cart or bank transfer.

Here is the result when I used Paypal live API

[image: Here is the result when I used Paypal live API]

But my expected result should be like that and work for Paypal sandbox test API
[image]

I am looking forward to your response and Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the live account a german (DE) account?

Comment: Hi Preston, the live account is a German DE account

Answer (score 0):

this can also relate to the buyers billing address.

> Based on the billing address country provided, buyers see PayPal's available funding sources for their country of origin

Comment: Yes I updated the billing address to Germany. But still doesn't work too

Comment: if it was recently changed, it does not work right away. do you have another pp live account to test that? sandbox just reflects the prod

Comment: I don't have another live account. It must be a business account and I have only one

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the live account is not enabled for this feature, which is not on by default. The account owner should contact PayPal's general customer support via https://www.paypal.com/smarthelp/contact-us to request it

If you are positive the account has the feature enabled, then you should ask PayPal's technical support to review the account: paypal.com/mts